# Multi-Class Document Classification with both known and un-known classes

Tags: text-classification, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification, document-classification

Currently, I am building a multi-class document classifier which has to classify either 3 known classes, namely "Financial Report", "Insurance_Sheet", "Endorsement", and 1 unknown class which is "Random Doc".
The following methods have been trialed, but did not prove a good result as quite a number of random documents have been classified as the known classes: "Financial Report", "Insurance_Sheet", "Endorsement".

- Method 1: TD-IDF + Linear SVC
- Method 2: Word2Vec for word embedding, then average those word-embedding to get the embedding vector for each document then feed to a classification model.
- Method 3: Doc2Vec to get the embedding vector for each document and then feed to a classification model.

Can you help suggest a good approach for this case ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, please ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ for design questions. In short: multiclass classification requires a representative sample for every class, it's likely that you can't have this for "random doc". Instead you could try some form of anomaly detection or [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) in order to recognize "regular documents" from "anything else". After this first step the classifier would deal only with the 3 regular classes.

Comment: Oh, sure, I will ask on the datascience stackexchange. Thanks Erwan, that is a good suggestion, will try to implement one-class classification in order to recognize "regular documents" from "anything else" then go through next step of known classification.